# Android Passing values from one activity to other activity (string) or from one class to another

Tags: android, class, spinner

I have two class Profile.class and Details.class,

In profile class i have used a spinner with values like (ATM,Banking,Personal,Others etc)
and a button (OK).
on clicking ok button it will go to next activity that is details activity where i will be taking some details like-name,description etc.

after filling the details i have given a button (save).
on clicking button save i will be saving the name and description in database but i want to save the profile name also along with details. i am unable to transfer selected spinner text from Profile.class to Details.class

how to transfer?

create.class  code

public class Create extends Activity {

```
    public ArrayList<String> array_spinner;
    Button button4;
    String spinnertext;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        array_spinner=new ArrayList<String>();
        array_spinner.add("ATM");
        array_spinner.add("Bank");
        array_spinner.add("Mail");


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setLongClickable(true);
        spinner.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                return false;

       }}
       );


        button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent4 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Details.class); 
                startActivityForResult(myIntent4, 0);

                myIntent4 .putExtra("key", array_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                startActivity(myIntent4);
            }

        });

}}
```

details.class  code

public class Details extends Activity {

```
EditText editText4,editText5,editText6;
Button button8,button9,button10;
TextView textView7;
String et4,et5,et6;
//SQLite Database db;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details);

    String spinnervalue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key");
```

please kindly explain me what is this "key"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("YourValueKey", yourData.getText().toString());
```

then you can get it from your second activity by :

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String YourtransferredData = intent.getExtras().getString("YourValueKey");
```

example

this is what you have to write in your first activity

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Product.class);
 i.putExtra("productname", ori);
 i.putExtra("productcost", position);
 i.startActivityForResult(i,0);
```

then in your next activity you need to have this code

```
 String productname,productcost;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.product);

    tv1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);

     Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
     if(extras!=null)
     {
        position = extras.getString("position"); // get the value based on the key
        tv1.setText(productname);//use where ever you want
        productname = extras.getString("productname"); // get the value based on the key 
        tv2.setText(productname);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all take a spinner and provide value to them what you want and then the selected spinner value change it to string value and this string variable will be used in OK button to pass value through use of **Intent** or **Shared preference** to take this value to another activity and through there you can use it in database to display this value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send data to another activity, you can do it using `intent`.

```
Bundle bund = new Bundle();

bund.putString("myKey",name);

Intent intent = new Intent(Profile.this, Detail.class);

intent.putExtras(bund);

startActivity(intent);
```

Now in Detail class, receive this data in onCreate()

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      .......

    String nameReceived = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myKey");
}
```

I have given the example of passing String to another activity however, you can pass boolean, int, double etc to another activity. See the full list on [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)